# What's the name of the top-level directory

Tags: directory, filenames, directory-structure

I am using Ubuntu.

I know by using `cd ~/` , I can go to *home/* directory.

But if I want to go to the directory (I do not know the official name of this directory) which contains `etc/`, `var/`, `opt/`, ... sub-directories, what is the symbol used to refer to this directory? (And by the way what is the official name of this directory? root directory?)

Basically, I would like to `cd` to that directory without using `cd ..` but one symbol to refer to it, is there such a symbol for it (like `~` refers to home directory)?

Comment: Btw, you can use `cd` without args to go to your home.

Comment: and you dont have to write the leading `/` -- `cd ~` without the `/` is enough

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This directory is called **the root directory** and is referenced by the symbol "/"

You can try `cd /` to go there.

Notice that if you try this:

```
$ cd /
$ cd ..
```

You're still at the root directory.

**NB**: Every Unix system has a super user account called **root**, whose home directory is `/root`. I know it's redundant, it can be ambiguous and lead to confusion. So make sure, every time you mention "root" to know whether it refers to the directory `/` or the (super)user.

Comment: do you mean "cd .." will stop when it reaches the root directory? Can I understand in this way?

Comment: Yes that's a very good way to look at it. My advice to you is to experiment as much as you can and read a unix tutorial. (hint: `pwd` will output your current working directory)

Comment: It's the root of the tree and is written as /. In node parlance, everything branches off from root until you get to the leaf nodes (files)